# IoT-AgentUL how to get data

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Currently I've got my own LoRaWAN network, with around 45 devices sending data with this payload: ID=D0001&T=23&H=60 where ID is the sensorId; T-Temperature; H - Humidity.

What steps do I have to make next to get context from my devices?

These are the steps that I've made:

1 - Installed IoT-Agent Ultralight

2 - Configured MQTT on the config.js file with my MQTT data

*config.mqtt = {
host: 'HOST_NAME',
port: 1883,
protocol : `mqtt`,
username: 'USERNAME',
password: 'PASSWORD',
retain: false,
retries: 5,
retryTime: 5,
keepalive: 0,
avoidLeadingSlash: false
};*

3 - IoTAgent-ul (node bin/iot-agentul), getting this message: *time=2020-12-01T10:44:48.197Z | lvl=INFO | corr=526cdc56-62b8-4791-b95d-f5110ca18b7e | trans=526cdc56-62b8-4791-b95d-f5110ca18b7e | op=IOTAUL.MQTT.Binding | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=connected | comp=IoTAgent*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear whether you need the [IoT Agent for Ultralight](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul) or the [IoT Agent for LoRaWAN](https://github.com/Atos-Research-and-Innovation/IoTagent-LoRaWAN). Ultralight is a payload syntax, the Ultralight IoT Agent supports HTTP, MQTT and AMPQ transports. LoRaWAN is a transport, it supports a couple of COAP protocols.

If you are really sending LoRa COAP messages then you'll need the LoRaWAN agent.

If you are using Ultralight over MQTT, then your message payload should look like this

```
ID|D0001|T|23|H|60
```

An [Ultralight over MQTT Tutorial](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.IoT-over-MQTT) exists within the Step-by-Step Guide.

If you are using COAP over LoRaWAN, then your message payload would be a stream of `base64` bytes coming from the LoRa gateway. The [Things network tutorial](https://github.com/Atos-Research-and-Innovation/IoTagent-LoRaWAN/blob/master/docs/tutorialStm32TTN.md) describes the set-up.

If your payload literally is: `ID=D0001&T=23&H=60`, you're going to need to create your own parser like the [Custom IoT Agent Tutorial](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Custom-IoT-Agent) and follow the steps in altering the IoT Agent codebase.

Specifically, the flow of control with the `HTTPBindings` [parseData()](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/blob/master/lib/bindings/HTTPBindings.js#L80) function. The `ulParser` would need to be re-written to accept your alternate syntax. It looks similar enough that all you'd need to do is:

```js
if (payload) {
    data = ulParser.parse(payload.replace(/&/g, "|").replace(/=/g, "|"));
}
```

(Even better if that could be done prior to sending to the Ultralight IoT Agent)

The advantage of re-using an existing IoT Agent (or writing a new one using the IoT Agent Node lib) is that functions such as the creation of entities and mapping of attributes is achieved using the existing code.

Comment: I have access to LoRaWAN and I can define the entry point via HTTP. I will point it out to the domain and port in config.http. The devices I work with send data from LoRaWAN in a Base64 format which translates into the payload above. Then, if I understood correctly, change the HTTPBindings.js in order to configure my own IoT Agent.

Is it needed, afterwards, to create a new entity per each new device? Or it is automatically created?

Thank you for the help Jason